# “combine” 2 regex with a logic or?

Tags: javascript, regex, logic

I have two patterns for javascript:

`/^[A-z0-9]{10}$/`  - string of exactly length of 10 of alphanumeric symbols.

and

`/^\d+$/`   - any number of at least length of one.

How to make the expression of OR string of 10 or any number?

`var pattern = /^([A-z0-9]{10})|(\d+)$/;`

doesn't work by some reason. It passes at lest

```
pattern.test("123kjhkjhkj33f");  // true
```

which is not number and not of length of 10 for `A-z0-9` string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that your `^([A-z0-9]{10})|(\d+)$` pattern matches 10 chars from the `A-z0-9` ranges at the start of the string (the `^` only modifies the `([A-z0-9]{10})` part (the first alternative branch), or (`|`) 1 or more digits at the end of the stirng with `(\d+)$` (the `$` only modifies the `(\d+)` branch pattern.

Also note that the `A-z` is a typo, [`[A-z]` does not only match ASCII letters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29771926/3832970).

You need to fix it as follows:

```
var pattern = /^(?:[A-Za-z0-9]{10}|\d+)$/;
```

or with the `i` modifier:

```
var pattern = /^(?:[a-z0-9]{10}|\d+)$/i;
```

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/W7elv4/1).

Note that *grouping* is important here: the `(?:...|...)` makes the anchors apply to each of them appropriately.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - a non-capturing alternation group:

  - `[A-Za-z0-9]{10}` - 10 alphanumeric chars
  - `|` - or
  - `\d+` - 1  or more digits
- `)` - end of the grouping construct
- `$` - end of string